# Declaring a function so that one of its arguments determines the stopping condition of a while loop (R)

Tags: r

I want to declare a function consisting basically in a while loop, but with the possibility of either setting its stopping condition to be reaching a certain number of iterations or reaching a certain threshold of time. My attempt at doing it is below.

```
my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
  if (units == "iterations") {
    i = 0
    while (i < stop_at) {
      #Main Act, then update value of i#
      i = i + 1
    }
  }

  ##Otherwise, units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")
  else {
    starting_time = Sys.time()
    while (difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = units) < stop_at) {
      #Main Act#
    }
  }
}
```

This certainly works, but it involves writing the `#Main Act#` chunk of code twice. This approach can be very dumb if what we want the function to do on each iteration involves writing several lines of code.

Instead, I would like the function to define the stopping condition according to the units argument that we pass to it —something along the lines of `if (units == "iterations") {condition = something} else {condition = some other thing}`— and then run `while (condition) {Do the main act}`. But I don't know how exactly could this be done —neither do I know if it's even possible—.

Comment: One option is simply to put `#Main Act#` in a second function.  Or put your compund condition in a function and pass that function as an argument to `my_function` in place of `stop_at` and `units`.  Using the elipsis (`...`) would probably be helpful in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `expression`, and `eval`uate it in the while condition:

```
i <- NA
my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
  if (units == "iterations") {
    i <-0
    condition = expression(i < stop_at)
  } else {
    condition = expression(difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = units) < stop_at)
  }

    while (eval(condition)) {
      #Main Act#
      if (!is.na(i)) i <- i + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Or one step further to handle `i+1` in the condition:

```
my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
  if (units == "iterations") {
    i <-0
    condition = expression({i <- i + 1; i < stop_at + 1})
  } else {
    condition = expression(difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = units) < stop_at)
  }
  
  while (eval(condition)) {
    #Main Act#
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions can be combined because when only one of it is FALSE the iteration stops.

```r
library(purrr)

my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
    
    i = 0
    starting_time = Sys.time()
    while (i < units && difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = 'secs') < stop_at) {
        i = i + 1
    }
    
    
    return(i)
}

my_function(stop_at = 2, 500)
#> [1] 500
my_function(stop_at = 0.002, 500)
#> [1] 71
my_function(stop_at = 0.004, 500)
#> [1] 143

map_dbl(seq(10000, 1000000, 100000), ~my_function(4, .x))
#>  [1]  10000 110000 193917 196160 202189 191101 194226 199465 192924 195735
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer:  just make a more complex condition in your `while` loop:

```
my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
    i <- 0
    starting_time <- Sys.time()
    while ((units == "iterations" && i < stop_at) ||
           (units != "iterations" && 
            difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = units) < stop_at)) {
      #Main Act, then update value of i#
      i <- i + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the first part of my comment above:

```
my_function = function(stop_at, units) {
  if (units == "iterations") {
    i = 0
    while (i < stop_at) {
      main_act()
      i = i + 1
    }
  }
  
  ##Otherwise, units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks")
  else {
    starting_time = Sys.time()
    while (difftime(Sys.time(), starting_time, units = units) < stop_at) {
      main_act()
    }
  }
}

main_act <- function() {
  print(paste("Main act at ", Sys.time()))
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
}

my_function(5, "iterations")
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:06"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:06"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:06"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:07"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:07"

my_function(2, "secs")
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:28"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:29"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:29"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:29"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:29"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:29"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:30"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:30"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:30"
[1] "Main act at  2021-06-06 07:11:30"
```